# Cannot resolve method 'ok(?)' with Play 2 Framework in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have been trying to get play set up in IntelliJ for hours but I can't get it to work correctly.

I continuously get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5OBY.jpg

I have tried create a project though the terminal with:

```
play new
```

and then using the terminal to create the idea files with

```
idea with-sources=yes
```

I have also installed the [play 2 plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7080) and used it to create the project, but I get the same error.

I am able to use the plugin I downloaded to successfully run the app and view it in my browser, but I keep getting the

```
Cannot resolve method 'ok(?)' error.
```

edit: I am using OSX, and have the ultimate version of Intellij.
edit 2: I have made a little progress.  If I import the view directly using import views.html.index; it gets rid of the errors on the application.  However, if I use import views.html.*; it results in the errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: this problem exists in IntelliJ 14 Ultimate as well.

Comment: 2016 ultimate as well. sad.

Comment: @Amalgovinus pretty horrible that this hasn't been fixed 4 years later

Comment: Although intellij complains about it, you should still be able to compile the code through ant or otherwise. Maybe make sure you're using a jar with the org.codehaus jackson packages and not the newer ones with "fasterxml" in the package name.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, it seems that play2 support in IntelliJ 13 Ultimate has some minor problems...

How I did solve the issues:

1) Navigate to your project director and start your play console (play.bat / play.sh should be on the PATH)

2) enter command 'compile' in your play console

3) enter command 'idea" in your play console

4a) in case your IntelliJ project was alread open, IntelliJ will detect the changes and suggest to reload the project. Confirm you want to reload

4b) in case IntelliJ was not running, open the project by File | Open... and select your project Directory.

These steps should resolve your issue.

Comment: These steps does not help me to solve the problem in IntelliJ 13.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to make sure that play has compiled the templates to class files, 'run' + open in browser or 'compile'?

Comment: This does not fix the issue.  Oddly I am able to compile in IntelliJ also.

Comment: Okay so I have made a little progress.  If I import the view directly using import views.html.index; it gets rid of the errors on the application.  However, if I use import views.html.*; it results in the errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, not really, have you looked in the Intellij bugtracker/filed a bug report?